# Ferial class option of evweek does not work with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I am trying to produce a two page weekly calendar using package `evweek` with the class option `ferial`.

The following file works fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ferial]{evweek}
\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{weekly}%
{   firstday=1,
    pageheight=280mm, 
    pagewidth=181mm,
    topspace=0.5mm, 
    bottomspace=0mm, 
    grip=0mm, 
    punchpoints=0, 
    punchcluster=0,
    punchgroups=0
 }%
{}
may 6 2013 to may 12 2013
\end{weekly}
\end{document}
```

Since I need the weekly calendar to be in Greek I used XeLaTeX which works with the previous file but does not work when `\usepackage{fontspec}` is added:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ferial]{evweek}
\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\begin{weekly}%
{   firstday=1,
    pageheight=280mm, 
    pagewidth=181mm,
    topspace=0.5mm, 
    bottomspace=0mm, 
    grip=0mm, 
    punchpoints=0, 
    punchcluster=0,
    punchgroups=0
 }%
{}
may 6 2013 to may 12 2013
\end{weekly}
\end{document}
```

What happens is that the two pages collapse to one and the output of the second page is superimposed on the first (albeit it is shifted to the bottom of the page).

Any ideas why this happens and how it could be fixed;

Comment: The other options (`traditional`, `compact`) of the package work fine with XeLaTeX, fontspec and Unicode Greek. It is just the two page option (`ferial`) that does not seem to work with `fontspec`.

Comment: same problem with LuaLaTeX, by the way.

Comment: Could you give details of where `evweek` and supporting material can be obtained from? It does not seem to be in TeX Live, and finding the `.cls` file alone gives me errors about other packages which I don't want to have to chase.

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/evweek which depends on **Calendar** package (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calendar) which in turn depends on **Dates** package. None of them is included in TexLive as far as I can tell from CTAN info.

Comment: `evweek`also depends on `evautofl` (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/evautofl)

Comment: Although all the above is correct if `calendar` is downloaded from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/calendar and run `latex allcal.ins` (answering yes to all questions) it contains `dates`, it also contains `evweek` and `evautofl` in `contrib` folder. Demo files can be found in root `calendar` directory as well as in `bigdemo.tgz`.